# Rerender #each block's contents on data change

Tags: ember.js

I have a controller which `content` is bound to an object, this object loads data asynchonously from different sources. I want data to be rendered when loading is done. This works just fine, but when I want to change data, #each block doesn't rerender it.

```
App.PopularTracks = Ember.Object.create({
    tracks: [],
    load: function() {
        var self = this;
        var tracks = [];

        LFM.get("chart.getHypedTracks", {limit: 5}, function(data) {
            // push each track to tracks in a loop, then
            self.set("tracks", tracks);
        });

        // This method has also other asynchronous calls that work similar,
        // but #each block doesn't rerender on `tracks` change.
    }
});

App.PopularTracksController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    contentBinding: "App.PopularTracks.tracks"
});

App.PopularTracksView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "popularTracks"
});
```

Comment: could you post a jsFiddle ? I want to see how you implement your each block

Answer (score 0):

In your example, should "self.set" be "this.set"?

Also using an arrayController, rather than targeting it's content like you would with a regular controller's property, you just target the content parameter:

```
{{#each controller}}
    print this for every item in the "content" array!
{{/each}}
```

If you do it like this:

```
{{#each controller.content}}
```

Some properties and bindings wont rerender properly